# Small badge progress display change

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-interface, edit-badges, badge-progress

When I'm in the review queue on Stack Overflow, I can hover over my badge progress and see something like this:

[image]

However, I do not have the [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) Badge yet. Why does it already show me the [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) badge? I think it should show Strunk & White, then have it transform into Copy Editor when I achieve S&W.

In contrast, it already does this functionality (I assume) for the [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer) badge, which I assume will transform to [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2279/steward) progress bar.

Comment: Why should it not show progress to `Copy Editor`? `Strunk & White` is but a stop on the way there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Because that behavior is inconsistent with the behavior for the progress display from Reviewer to Steward.  Reviewer is, as you say, but a stop on the way to Reviewer as well.

Comment: I sorta-kinda agree but don't care enough. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did say it was a small change :)

Comment: Well to be fair I don't much care either.  Otherwise I would have provided an answer to the question. :)